# (Why) Is there only one Lyapunov exponent?

Tags: chaos-theory, complex-systems

Lyapunov exponents describe how two (infinitesimally) close initial conditions behave (exponentially) in the long run. If a system is chaotic, the largest Lyapunov exponent is positive. However, as far as I understand it, if we have say, three ODEs depending on time, each state variable has one Lyapunov exponent. But how?

If we consider
$$
\lambda = \lim_{t \to \infty} \lim_{\delta \mathbf{Z}_0 \to 0}
\frac{1}{t} \ln\frac{| \delta\mathbf{Z}(t)|}{|\delta \mathbf{Z}_0|},
$$
in my understanding, this would always tend to zero as $t\to\infty$ if we consider a chaotic attractor?!

What am I getting wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> each state variable has one Lyapunov exponent. But how?

The equation you give is for the *maximal* Lyapunov exponent, while what you're referring to here is Lyapunov *spectrum*.

You can find how to calculate it in almost any text on chaos theory - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_exponent) as usual could be a good start for getting the overall picture. This [previous answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/388691/75633) gives some pointers and references for the calculation, and [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/464497/75633) tries to say something about their meaning.

> this would always tend to zero as t→∞ if we consider a chaotic attractor?!

Nope. The factor $1/t$ goes linearly to zero, yes, but $\delta\mathbf{Z}(t)$ diverges exponentially for chaotic orbits, meaning that the factor $\ln | \delta\mathbf{Z}(t)|$ should diverge linearly and the whole thing converges, as also explained in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/232604/75633) for iterated systems.

Also notice the limit $\delta\mathbf{Z}(0) \to 0$, which means that the values that the equations return are *local* quantities for a specific orbit - so the divergence is local, that's how you can have finite exponents also for spatially confined orbits.